# Bounding volume hierarchy C++

Tags: c++, collision

Here is a C++ implementation of a bounding volume hierarchy, aimed for fast collision detection (view frustum, rays, other bounding volumes). It is based on the ideas from the book "Real-Time Rendering, Third Edition". Would like to hear some thoughts:

```cpp
#ifndef BOUNDINGVOLUMEHIERARCHY_H
#define BOUNDINGVOLUMEHIERARCHY_H

#include <Camera.h>
#include <vector>
#include <IntersectionTests.h>
#include <CullResult.h>
#include <Ray.h>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>

namespace Log2
{
  template<typename T, typename BV, typename Proxy, typename TNested>
  class BoundingVolumeHierarchy
  {
  public:
    class NodePool;

    static const auto Dim = BV::getDim();

    using Type = typename BV::Type;
    using Ray = Ray<Dim, Type>;
    using Vector = Vector<Dim, Type>;
    using Matrix = Matrix<Dim + 1, Dim + 1, Type>;

    struct PrimitiveInfo
    {
      T* _primitive;
      BV _bv;
      Type _bvSize;
    };
  private:
    auto getBV(const T& primitive)
    {
      return Proxy::GetBoundingVolume()(primitive);
    }
    auto getSize(const T& primitive)
    {
      return Proxy::GetLargestBVSize()(primitive);
    }
    PrimitiveInfo createInfo(T* primitive)
    {
      return { primitive, getBV(*primitive), getSize(*primitive) };
    }
  public:
    class Node
    {
    public:
      Node() = default;
      virtual ~Node() = default;
      virtual void cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const = 0;
      virtual void cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const IntersectedPlanes& in, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const = 0;
      virtual void cullAllPrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& primitives) const = 0;
      virtual size_t getSizeInBytes() const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectFirst(const BV& bv, T const *& first) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectFirst(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, T const *& first) const = 0;
      virtual void cullVisibleNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const = 0;
      virtual void cullAllNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const = 0;
      virtual void countNodes(unsigned& internal_nodes, unsigned& leaf_nodes) const = 0;
      virtual void getAllBVs(std::vector<BV>& bvs) const = 0;
      virtual void cullBVs(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<BV>& result) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const = 0;
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const = 0;
      virtual void findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const = 0;
      virtual void findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const = 0;
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const = 0;
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) = 0;
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const = 0;
      virtual void findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const = 0;
      virtual void findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) = 0;
      virtual void queryRange(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void queryAll(std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void queryRange(const BV& bv, const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual void queryAll(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const = 0;
      virtual bool isLeaf() const = 0;
      virtual Node* getLeft() const = 0;
      virtual Node* getRight() const = 0;
      virtual Node*& getLeft() = 0;
      virtual Node*& getRight() = 0;
      virtual T * getPrimitivePtr() = 0;
      virtual BV getBV() const = 0;
      virtual BV const * getBVPtr() const = 0;
      virtual BV * getBVPtr() = 0;
      virtual Type distToPoint2(const Vector& point) const = 0;
      virtual void destroy(NodePool& pool) = 0;
      virtual Type* getLargestBVSize() = 0;
      virtual Type cost(const BV& bv) const = 0;
    };
    class LeafNode : public Node
    {
    public:
      explicit LeafNode(T primitive)
        : Node(),
        _primitive(primitive)
      {
      }
      virtual ~LeafNode() = default;
      virtual void cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const override
      {
        cull_result._probablyVisiblePrimitives.push_back(_primitive);
      }
      virtual void cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const IntersectedPlanes& in, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const override
      {
        cull_result._probablyVisiblePrimitives.push_back(_primitive);
      }
      virtual void cullAllPrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& primitives) const override
      {
        primitives.push_back(_primitive);
      }
      virtual size_t getSizeInBytes() const override
      {
        return sizeof *this;
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(getBV())) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(BV(getBV(), transform))) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(getBV())) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(&_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(BV(getBV(), transform))) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(&_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectFirst(const BV& bv, T const *& first) const override
      {
        if (!first && bv.intersects(getBV())) {
          first = &_primitive;
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectFirst(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, T const *& first) const override
      {
        if (!first && bv.intersects(BV(getBV(), transform))) {
          first = &_primitive;
        }
      }
      virtual void cullVisibleNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp) && intersectFrustum(cp) != IntersectionResult::OUTSIDE) {
          nodes.push_back(this);
        }
      }
      virtual void cullAllNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          nodes.push_back(this);
        }
      }
      virtual void countNodes(unsigned& internal_nodes, unsigned& leaf_nodes) const override
      {
        leaf_nodes++;
      }
      virtual void getAllBVs(std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        bvs.push_back(getBV());
      }
      virtual void cullBVs(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<BV>& result) const override
      {
        BV bv(getBV(), transform);
        if (bv.contributes(cp._camPos, cp._thresh)) {
          result.push_back(bv);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(getBV(), ray))) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray))) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(getBV(), ray))) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
          bvs.push_back(getBV());
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray))) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
          bvs.push_back(BV(getBV(), transform));
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < nearest_t) {
          nearest = &_primitive;
          nearest_t = std::get<1>(result);
          nearest_transform = transform;
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < nearest_t) {
          nearest = &_primitive;
          nearest_t = std::get<1>(result);
          nearest_transform = transform;
          bvs.push_back(BV(getBV(), transform));
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray))) {
          auto result = Proxy::IntersectRay()(_primitive, ray, transform);
          if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<3>(result) < t) {
            nearest = &_primitive;
            nearest_transform = transform;
            u = std::get<1>(result);
            v = std::get<2>(result);
            t = std::get<3>(result);
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray))) {
          auto result = Proxy::IntersectRay()(_primitive, ray, transform);
          if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<3>(result) < t) {
            nearest = &_primitive;
            nearest_transform = transform;
            u = std::get<1>(result);
            v = std::get<2>(result);
            t = std::get<3>(result);
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(getBV(), transform), ray))) {
          auto result = Proxy::IntersectRay()(_primitive, ray, transform);
          if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<3>(result) < t) {
            nearest = &_primitive;
            nearest_transform = transform;
            u = std::get<1>(result);
            v = std::get<2>(result);
            t = std::get<3>(result);
            bvs.push_back(BV(getBV(), transform));
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const override
      {
        Proxy::FindNearestNestedConst()(_primitive, ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
      }
      virtual void findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) override
      {
        Proxy::FindNearestNested()(_primitive, ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
      }
      virtual void queryRange(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(getBV())) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void queryAll(std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
      }
      virtual void queryRange(const BV& bv, const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp) && bv.intersects(getBV())) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual void queryAll(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          intersected_primitives.push_back(_primitive);
        }
      }
      virtual bool isLeaf() const override
      {
        return true;
      }
      virtual Node* getLeft() const override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
        return nullptr;
      }
      virtual Node* getRight() const override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
        return nullptr;
      }
      virtual Node*& getLeft() override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
      }
      virtual Node*& getRight() override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
      }
      virtual T * getPrimitivePtr() override
      {
        return &_primitive;
      }
      virtual BV getBV() const override
      {
        return Proxy::GetBoundingVolume()(_primitive);
      }
      virtual BV const * getBVPtr() const override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
        return nullptr;
      }
      virtual BV * getBVPtr() override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
        return nullptr;
      }
      virtual Type distToPoint2(const Vector& point) const override
      {
        return Proxy::GetBoundingVolume()(_primitive).distToPoint2(point);
      }
      virtual void destroy(NodePool& pool) override
      {
        pool.destroy(this);
      }
      virtual Type* getLargestBVSize() override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
        return nullptr;
      }
      virtual Type cost(const BV& bv) const override
      {
        return bv.getUnion(getBV()).size2();
      }
    private:
      T _primitive;
      auto contributes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp) const
      {
        return getBV().contributes(cp._camPos, cp._thresh, Proxy::GetLargestBVSize()(_primitive));
      }
      auto intersectFrustum(const Camera::CullingParams& cp) const
      {
        return IntersectionTests::frustumIntersectsBoundingVolume(getBV(), cp._frustumPlanes);
      }
    };
    using NodePtr = Node * ;
    class InternalNode : public Node
    {
    public:
      InternalNode(PrimitiveInfo* begin, PrimitiveInfo* end, BoundingVolumeHierarchy& bvh)
        : Node(),
        _bv(begin->_bv),
        _largestBVSize(begin->_bvSize)
      {
        for (auto const* ptr = begin + 1; ptr < end; ptr++) {
          _bv.unify(ptr->_bv);
          maximize(ptr->_bvSize, _largestBVSize);
        }
        auto axis = _bv.longestAxis();
        auto bv_center = _bv.center(axis);
        auto mid = std::partition(begin, end, [&axis, &bv_center](const PrimitiveInfo& p) {
          return p._bv.center(axis) < bv_center;
        });
        if (mid == begin || mid == end) {
          mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2u;
        }
        _left = bvh.createNode(begin, mid);
        _right = bvh.createNode(mid, end);
      }
      virtual ~InternalNode() = default;
      virtual void cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          auto result = intersectFrustum(cp);
          if (result == IntersectionResult::INTERSECTING) {
            _left->cullVisiblePrimitives(cp, cull_result);
            _right->cullVisiblePrimitives(cp, cull_result);
          }
          else if (result == IntersectionResult::INSIDE) {
            _left->cullAllPrimitives(cp, cull_result._fullyVisiblePrimitives);
            _right->cullAllPrimitives(cp, cull_result._fullyVisiblePrimitives);
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const IntersectedPlanes& in, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          IntersectedPlanes out;
          auto result = intersectFrustum(cp, in, out);
          if (result == IntersectionResult::INTERSECTING) {
            _left->cullVisiblePrimitives(cp, out, cull_result);
            _right->cullVisiblePrimitives(cp, out, cull_result);
          }
          else if (result == IntersectionResult::INSIDE) {
            _left->cullAllPrimitives(cp, cull_result._fullyVisiblePrimitives);
            _right->cullAllPrimitives(cp, cull_result._fullyVisiblePrimitives);
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void cullAllPrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& primitives) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          _left->cullAllPrimitives(cp, primitives);
          _right->cullAllPrimitives(cp, primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual size_t getSizeInBytes() const override
      {
        return sizeof *this + _left->getSizeInBytes() + _right->getSizeInBytes();
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(_bv)) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(bv, intersected_primitives);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(bv, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(BV(_bv, transform))) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(bv, transform, intersected_primitives);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(bv, transform, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(_bv)) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(bv, intersected_primitives);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(bv, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.intersects(BV(_bv, transform))) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(bv, transform, intersected_primitives);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(bv, transform, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectFirst(const BV& bv, T const *& first) const override
      {
        if (!first && bv.intersects(_bv)) {
          _left->intersectFirst(bv, first);
          _right->intersectFirst(bv, first);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectFirst(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, T const *& first) const override
      {
        if (!first && bv.intersects(BV(_bv, transform))) {
          _left->intersectFirst(bv, transform, first);
          _right->intersectFirst(bv, transform, first);
        }
      }
      virtual void cullVisibleNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          auto result = intersectFrustum(cp);
          if (result == IntersectionResult::INSIDE) {
            nodes.push_back(this);
            _left->cullAllNodes(cp, nodes);
            _right->cullAllNodes(cp, nodes);
          }
          else if (result == IntersectionResult::INTERSECTING) {
            nodes.push_back(this);
            _left->cullVisibleNodes(cp, nodes);
            _right->cullVisibleNodes(cp, nodes);
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void cullAllNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          nodes.push_back(this);
          _left->cullAllNodes(cp, nodes);
          _right->cullAllNodes(cp, nodes);
        }
      }
      virtual void countNodes(unsigned& internal_nodes, unsigned& leaf_nodes) const override
      {
        internal_nodes++;
        _left->countNodes(internal_nodes, leaf_nodes);
        _right->countNodes(internal_nodes, leaf_nodes);
      }
      virtual void getAllBVs(std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        bvs.push_back(_bv);
        _left->getAllBVs(bvs);
        _right->getAllBVs(bvs);
      }
      virtual void cullBVs(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<BV>& result) const override
      {
        BV bv(_bv, transform);
        if (bv.contributes(cp._camPos, cp._thresh)) {
          result.push_back(bv);
          _left->cullBVs(cp, transform, result);
          _right->cullBVs(cp, transform, result);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(_bv, ray))) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(ray, intersected_primitives);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(ray, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray))) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(ray, transform, intersected_primitives);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(ray, transform, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(_bv, ray))) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(ray, intersected_primitives, bvs);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(ray, intersected_primitives, bvs);
          bvs.push_back(_bv);
        }
      }
      virtual void intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        if (std::get<0>(IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray))) {
          _left->intersectPrimitives(ray, transform, intersected_primitives, bvs);
          _right->intersectPrimitives(ray, transform, intersected_primitives, bvs);
          bvs.push_back(BV(_bv, transform));
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < nearest_t) {
          _left->findNearest(ray, transform, nearest, nearest_t, nearest_transform);
          _right->findNearest(ray, transform, nearest, nearest_t, nearest_transform);
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < nearest_t) {
          bvs.push_back(BV(_bv, transform));
          _left->findNearest(ray, transform, nearest, nearest_t, nearest_transform, bvs);
          _right->findNearest(ray, transform, nearest, nearest_t, nearest_transform, bvs);
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < t) {
          _left->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
          _right->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < t) {
          _left->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
          _right->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(BV(_bv, transform), ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < t) {
          bvs.push_back(BV(_bv, transform));
          _left->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform, bvs);
          _right->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform, bvs);
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(_bv, ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < t) {
          Node* nodes[2] = { _left, _right };
          auto result = _left->distToPoint2(ray.getOrigin()) < _right->distToPoint2(ray.getOrigin());
          nodes[!result]->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
          nodes[result]->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
        }
      }
      virtual void findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) override
      {
        auto result = IntersectionTests::rayIntersectsBoundingVolume(_bv, ray);
        if (std::get<0>(result) && std::get<1>(result) < t) {
          Node* nodes[2] = { _left, _right };
          auto result = _left->distToPoint2(ray.getOrigin()) < _right->distToPoint2(ray.getOrigin());
          nodes[!result]->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
          nodes[result]->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
        }
      }
      virtual void queryRange(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (bv.contains(_bv)) {
          _left->queryAll(intersected_primitives);
          _right->queryAll(intersected_primitives);
        }
        else if (bv.intersects(_bv)) {
          _left->queryRange(bv, intersected_primitives);
          _right->queryRange(bv, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual void queryAll(std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        _left->queryAll(intersected_primitives);
        _right->queryAll(intersected_primitives);
      }
      virtual void queryRange(const BV& bv, const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          if (bv.contains(_bv)) {
            _left->queryAll(cp, intersected_primitives);
            _right->queryAll(cp, intersected_primitives);
          }
          else if (bv.intersects(_bv)) {
            _left->queryRange(bv, cp, intersected_primitives);
            _right->queryRange(bv, cp, intersected_primitives);
          }
        }
      }
      virtual void queryAll(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const override
      {
        if (contributes(cp)) {
          _left->queryAll(cp, intersected_primitives);
          _right->queryAll(cp, intersected_primitives);
        }
      }
      virtual bool isLeaf() const override
      {
        return false;
      }
      virtual Node* getLeft() const override
      {
        return _left;
      }
      virtual Node* getRight() const override
      {
        return _right;
      }
      virtual Node*& getLeft() override
      {
        return _left;
      }
      virtual Node*& getRight() override
      {
        return _right;
      }
      virtual T * getPrimitivePtr() override
      {
        throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
        return nullptr;
      }
      virtual BV getBV() const override
      {
        return _bv;
      }
      virtual BV const * getBVPtr() const override
      {
        return &_bv;
      }
      virtual BV * getBVPtr() override
      {
        return &_bv;
      }
      virtual Type distToPoint2(const Vector& point) const override
      {
        return _bv.distToPoint2(point);
      }
      virtual void destroy(NodePool& pool) override
      {
        pool.destroy(this);
      }
      virtual Type* getLargestBVSize() override
      {
        return &_largestBVSize;
      }
      virtual Type cost(const BV& bv) const override
      {
        return bv.getUnion(_bv).size2();
      }
    private:
      NodePtr _left, _right;
      BV _bv;
      Type _largestBVSize;
      auto contributes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp) const
      {
        return _bv.contributes(cp._camPos, cp._thresh, _largestBVSize);
      }
      auto intersectFrustum(const Camera::CullingParams& cp) const
      {
        return IntersectionTests::frustumIntersectsBoundingVolume(_bv, cp._frustumPlanes);
      }
      auto intersectFrustum(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const IntersectedPlanes& in, IntersectedPlanes& out) const
      {
        return IntersectionTests::frustumIntersectsBoundingVolume(_bv, cp._frustumPlanes, in, out);
      }
    };
    BoundingVolumeHierarchy() = delete;
    BoundingVolumeHierarchy(T* primitives, unsigned count) :
      _nodePool(count)
    {
      std::vector<PrimitiveInfo> infos;
      infos.reserve(count);
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        infos.push_back(createInfo(primitives + i));
      }
      _root = createNode(infos.data(), infos.data() + count);
    }
    BoundingVolumeHierarchy(const BoundingVolumeHierarchy& other) = delete;
    BoundingVolumeHierarchy& operator=(const BoundingVolumeHierarchy& other) = delete;
    BoundingVolumeHierarchy(BoundingVolumeHierarchy&& other) = default;
    BoundingVolumeHierarchy& operator=(BoundingVolumeHierarchy&& other) = default;
    auto cullVisiblePrimitives(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const
    {
      _root->cullVisiblePrimitives(cp, cull_result);
    }
    auto cullVisiblePrimitivesWithPlaneMasking(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, CullResult<T>& cull_result) const
    {
      IntersectedPlanes out = { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 6 };
      _root->cullVisiblePrimitives(cp, out, cull_result);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(bv, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(bv, transform, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(bv, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T const *>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(bv, transform, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto intersectFirst(const BV& bv, T const *& first) const
    {
      _root->intersectFirst(bv, first);
    }
    auto intersectFirst(const BV& bv, const Matrix& transform, T const *& first) const
    {
      _root->intersectFirst(bv, transform, first);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(ray, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(ray, transform, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& intersected_bvs) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(ray, intersected_primitives, intersected_bvs);
    }
    auto intersectPrimitives(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives, std::vector<BV>& intersected_bvs) const
    {
      _root->intersectPrimitives(ray, transform, intersected_primitives, intersected_bvs);
    }
    auto findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T*& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const
    {
      _root->findNearest(ray, transform, nearest, nearest_t, nearest_transform);
    }
    auto findNearest(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T*& nearest, Type& nearest_t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const
    {
      _root->findNearest(ray, transform, nearest, nearest_t, nearest_transform, bvs);
    }
    auto findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const
    {
      _root->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
    }
    auto findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const
    {
      _root->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
    }
    auto findNearestPrecise(const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform, T const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const
    {
      _root->findNearestPrecise(ray, transform, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform, bvs);
    }
    auto cullVisibleNodes(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<Node const *>& nodes) const
    {
      _root->cullVisibleNodes(cp, nodes);
    }
    auto findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const
    {
      _root->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
    }
    auto findNearestNested(const Ray& ray, TNested *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const
    {
      _root->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
    }
    auto queryRange(const BV& bv, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->queryRange(bv, intersected_primitives);
    }
    auto queryRange(const BV& bv, const Camera::CullingParams& cp, std::vector<T>& intersected_primitives) const
    {
      _root->queryRange(bv, cp, intersected_primitives);
    }
    template<typename OtherNodePtr, typename OtherT, typename OtherProxy>
    void findOverlappingPairs(NodePtr a, OtherNodePtr b, const Matrix& a_transform, std::vector<std::tuple<T*, OtherT*>>& overlapping_pairs) const
    {
      if (!a->isLeaf() && !b->isLeaf()) {
        auto a_bv = BV(*a->getBVPtr(), a_transform);
        if (a_bv.intersects(*b->getBVPtr())) {
          if (a_bv.size2() > b->getBVPtr()->size2()) {
            findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a->getLeft(), b, a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
            findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a->getRight(), b, a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
          }
          else {
            findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a, b->getLeft(), a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
            findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a, b->getRight(), a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
          }
        }
      }
      else if (a->isLeaf() && b->isLeaf()) {
        auto a_bv = BV(Proxy::GetBoundingVolume()(*a->getPrimitivePtr()), a_transform);
        auto b_bv = OtherProxy::GetBoundingVolume()(*b->getPrimitivePtr());
        if (a_bv.intersects(b_bv)) {
          overlapping_pairs.push_back(std::tuple<T*, OtherT*>(a->getPrimitivePtr(), b->getPrimitivePtr()));
        }
      }
      else if (a->isLeaf() && !b->isLeaf()) {
        if (BV(a->getBV(), a_transform).intersects(*b->getBVPtr())) {
          findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a, b->getLeft(), a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
          findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a, b->getRight(), a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
        }
      }
      else { // a is internal and b is leaf node
        if (BV(*a->getBVPtr(), a_transform).intersects(b->getBV())) {
          findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a->getLeft(), b, a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
          findOverlappingPairs<OtherNodePtr, OtherT, OtherProxy>(a->getRight(), b, a_transform, overlapping_pairs);
        }
      }
    }
    auto insert(T primitive)
    {
      insert(primitive, _root);
    }
    auto getSizeInBytes() const
    {
      return _root->getSizeInBytes();
    }
    const auto& getBV() const
    {
      return _root->getBV();
    }
    const auto& getRoot() const
    {
      return _root;
    }
    auto getAllBVs() const
    {
      std::vector<BV> bvs;
      _root->getAllBVs(bvs);
      return bvs;
    }
    auto cullBVs(const Camera::CullingParams& cp, const Matrix& transform, std::vector<BV>& bvs) const
    {
      _root->cullBVs(cp, transform, bvs);
    }
    auto countNodes(unsigned& internal_nodes, unsigned& leaf_nodes) const
    {
      internal_nodes = 0;
      leaf_nodes = 0;
      _root->countNodes(internal_nodes, leaf_nodes);
    }
  private:
    auto insert(T primitive, Node*& node)
    {
      if (!node->isLeaf()) {
        node->getBVPtr()->unify(getBV(primitive));
        maximize(getSize(primitive), *node->getLargestBVSize());
        insert(primitive, node->getLeft()->cost(getBV(primitive)) < node->getRight()->cost(getBV(primitive)) ? node->getLeft() : node->getRight());
      }
      else {
        PrimitiveInfo primitives[2] = { createInfo(&primitive), createInfo(node->getPrimitivePtr()) };
        node->destroy(_nodePool);
        node = createNode(primitives, primitives + 2);
      }
    }
    class NodePool
    {
    public:
      NodePool(unsigned num_primitives)
      {
        auto height = static_cast<unsigned>(std::floor(log2(static_cast<double>(num_primitives))));
        auto num_nodes = static_cast<unsigned>(std::pow(2.0, static_cast<double>(height) + 1.0) - 1.0);
        auto num_leaf_nodes = static_cast<unsigned>(std::pow(2.0, static_cast<double>(height)));
        auto num_internal_nodes = num_nodes - num_leaf_nodes;
        maximize(32u, num_leaf_nodes);
        maximize(32u, num_internal_nodes);
        _internalNodePool.set_next_size(num_internal_nodes);
        _leafNodePool.set_next_size(num_leaf_nodes);
      }
      NodePool(const NodePool& other) = delete;
      NodePool& operator=(const NodePool& other) = delete;
      NodePool(NodePool&& other) = delete;
      NodePool& operator=(NodePool&& other) = delete;
      Node* createNode(PrimitiveInfo* begin, PrimitiveInfo* end, BoundingVolumeHierarchy& bvh)
      {
        if (end - begin > 1) {
          return new (_internalNodePool.malloc()) InternalNode(begin, end, bvh);
        }
        return new (_leafNodePool.malloc()) LeafNode(*begin->_primitive);
      }
      auto destroy(LeafNode* node)
      {
        _leafNodePool.destroy(node);
      }
      auto destroy(InternalNode* node)
      {
        _internalNodePool.destroy(node);
      }
    private:
      boost::object_pool<InternalNode> _internalNodePool;
      boost::object_pool<LeafNode> _leafNodePool;
    };
    NodePool _nodePool;
    auto* createNode(PrimitiveInfo* begin, PrimitiveInfo* end)
    {
      return _nodePool.createNode(begin, end, *this);
    }
    Node* _root;
  };
}

#endif
```

**Edit:**
Here is a sample use, in my Renderer class, I have this:

```
  struct Proxy
    {
      struct GetBoundingVolume
      {
        const BV& operator()(const MeshRenderablePtr& ptr) const
        {
          return ptr->getBV();
        }
      };
      struct GetLargestBVSize
      {
        auto operator()(const MeshRenderablePtr& ptr) const
        {
          return ptr->getLargestObjectBVSize();
        }
      };
      struct IntersectRay
      {
        auto operator()(const MeshRenderablePtr& ptr, const Ray& ray, const Matrix& transform) const
        {
          throw std::exception("Don't call this method");
          return std::tuple<bool, float, float, float>();
        }
      };
      struct FindNearestNestedConst
      {
        auto operator()(const MeshRenderablePtr& ptr, const Ray& ray, Triangle const *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform) const
        {
          ptr->getGPUMeshData()->getMesh().getBVH().findNearestPrecise(ray, *ptr->getModelMatrix(), nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
        }
      };
      struct FindNearestNested
      {
        auto operator()(const MeshRenderablePtr& ptr, const Ray& ray, Triangle *& nearest, Type& u, Type& v, Type& t, Matrix& nearest_transform)
        {
          ptr->getGPUMeshData()->getMesh().getBVH().findNearestPrecise(ray, *ptr->getModelMatrix(), nearest, u, v, t, nearest_transform);
        }
      };
    };
    using BVH = BoundingVolumeHierarchy<MeshRenderable*, BV, Proxy, Triangle>;
```

Usage:

```
auto ray = _renderer.getRay(_mousePos);
Triangle const * nearest = nullptr;
Mat4f nearest_transform;
float u, v;
float nearest_t = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
_renderer.getStaticBVH()->findNearestNested(ray, nearest, u, v, nearest_t, nearest_transform);
if (nearest) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Quite a lot of context is missing, so I'm guessing some things. e.g.:

  - What's `BV`?
  - What's `BV::Type`? (apparently it's a size, but for some reason it's stored outside the `BV` itself? Seems a bit odd if we have our own copy of the BV.)
  - What is `maximize`? (I'd guess `a = std::max(a, b)`, but that can't be right because `maximize(getSize(primitive), *node->getLargestBVSize());` wouldn't work).

---

- The constructor should take a `T const*`.
- Various functions (e.g. `createNode`) taking `PrimitiveInfo*` can be `PrimitiveInfo const*`.
- `createInfo` could take a `T const*`, be made static, and then simply deleted.
- `getBV` and `getSize` can be static.

---

- The `Proxy` class is confusing.

  - Why use nested structs with `operator()`, instead of simple static functions?
  - It injects a whole lot of unnecessary complexity into the `BVH` class. There's no reason for the `BVH` class to handle searches in a nested `BVH` that may or may not exist.
  - Enforcing an interface on the primitive type would be neater. (Why put a primitive with no `getBV()` in a bounding volume hierarchy?)

---

- Prefer returning a struct over a tuple, because you can name the members. It's hard to remember what each element of the tuple is for, the code isn't self-documenting, and it's easier to make mistakes with magic numbers than actual names.
- There's a lot of code duplication:

  - `intersectPrimitives(BV, vector)` and `queryRange(BV, vector)` are identical.
  - `findNearestPrecise` functions are nearly identical (factor out common functionality).
  - `intersectPrimitives` functions are nearly identical (factor out common functionality).

---

- I doubt the `BVH` class needs to know anything about culling or the camera. Can this be implemented as a simple `intersectsFrustum` function, and all of the rendering specific stuff done outside the class?

---

Design questions:

- Is inheritance really the best option for the nodes? Leaf nodes don't have left / right children, and internal nodes don't have a primitive, so some of the virtual functions don't really make sense either way. Perhaps a variant would be better, and all the search functions can then be implemented in the main class.
- Perhaps node creation should be done in the main class, instead of in InternalNode?
- Can traversal and action on the node be abstracted out? Most of the query / intersection functions seem to end up doing the following (pseudocode):

  ```
  do_thingy(traversal_condition, action):
      if is_leaf:
          if traversal_condition(node.bv)
              left.do_thingy()
              right.do_thingy()
          else
              return
      else
          action(node.primitive)
  ```

---

Comment: BV is some bounding volume, usually a box (AABB, OBB) or a sphere. Type is the underlying primitive data type like double, float, int etc. maximize() is actually defined by : template<typename T>
  static auto maximize(const T& other, T& out)
  {
    out = std::max(out, other);
  }
"Various functions (e.g. createNode) taking PrimitiveInfo* can be PrimitiveInfo const*." No, they can't, because I cannot call partition() then.

Comment: Good point. I'd missed the `partition`. However, I'd then suggest there's no reason to modify external data like that. If we need to modify it, we should take the data by value in the constructor.